Does every smooth homogeneous manifold have a Lie group acting simply transitively?
I have some smooth manifold $\mathcal{M}$. If there exists a Lie group $G$ that acts transitively on $\mathcal{M}$ does this imply that there exists a Lie group $H$ that acts simply transitively on $\mathcal{M}$?

$M$ would then be diffeomorphic to $H$, so it won't work e.g. for $M=S^2$ (e.g. because there is no everywhere nonzero vector field on $S^2$)
